# Geb using Navigator Methods on empty Navigators

Tags: jquery, geb

I am a little confused by the verbiage used for the navigator API found here http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/api/geb/navigator/Navigator.html

In particualr, I am confused by the .isDisplayed Method.

The method documentation states:
"Returns true if the sole context element is displayed or false for empty Navigators. Cannot be called on multi element Navigators."

The problem is if I call .isDisplayed() on an empty navigator it does not return false. Instead it throws this error:

```
table: geb.navigator.EmptyNavigator' is not present
```

The line it fails at looks something like this:

```
at SomePage //This page has a module element called "module"
if(module.table.isDiplayed()){ // module has a navigtor element called table
    //do stuff
}
```

The table element in question is indeed non-existant, so the table element is indeed an empty navigator, but according to the documentation that means that when I call .isDisplayed() it should return false but instead it throws the above mentioned error

this is the same case when calling simular navigator methods such as .isEmpty() 
again, if the the element is not found on the page I would expect .isEmpty() to return true when being called from the empty element, but instead it throws the EmptyNavigator exception.

What gives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the table element on module on your page is a required element (which is default). When you try to use a required page element, but the selector returns an empty navigator, geb will throw that exception. To fix this, you want to tell geb that the module is not required:

```
class Module{

  static content {
    table(required: false) { /* selector here*/ }
  }
}
```

Now when you use table, you will get the empty navigator back instead of the exception.

Comment: Yup this was it thanks. I still think the documentation is a little unclear on this though.